# Why is bind needed in this code?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working through the getting started tutorial and I don't understand this line:

```
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
```

from [this tutorial](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html).

Why not just do

```
db.on('error', ()=>{
  console.log('connection error:')
});
```

and where is the error information?

Comment: because, a) can't see the whole context of the code, so it may not be appropriate, and b) `=>` isn't supported on Internet Exploder at all, and c), the *real* equivalent would be `(...args)=>{
  console.error('connection error:', ...args)
}`

Comment: ... this is server side code.  Why are you bringing up internet explorer?

Comment: oh, right, it is too - my bad. I guess you can ignore b), but a) (to a small extent) still holds, and c) definitely holds, your two code snippets have virtually nothing in common :p

Comment: I don't understand the line with the arrow function, why is it *needed*? Why not just do use `bind`? :-P

Comment: @Bergi - normally on an error you can log the error information.  I would expect the callback to have a parameter that holds this information.  Wishful thinking?  Just saying "connection error:" is not too informative.

Comment: @rebeccakan Yes, as JaromandaX explained, the arrow function should indeed have a parameter to work properly and like the `bind` version

Comment: this seems to be a matter of preference than, I like my version obviously, but both are valid lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `bind` is a function that generates a new function out of the function it is called on and the resulting function already has the specific parameters "baked in".

The first parameter `bind` expects is special, so I'll get back to it in a moment. From the second param onward, these are the params you "bake in" to the new function.

Let's take `addTwoNumbers` for example:

```
function addTwoNumbers(a, b) {
    return a + b    
}
```

because `addTwoNumbers` is an object of type function we can call `bind` on it, pass in parameters, and get a new function. Like so:

```
var addThree = addTwoNumbers.bind(null, 3) // we have no use for "this" so we simply pass null as the first param
```

our new function `addThree` now expects only 1 parameter. It is functionally equivalent (for our purposes) to:

```
function addThree(b) {
    return addTwoNumbers(3, b)
}
```

so calling `addThree(4)` would result in `7`.

Now the first param of `bind` is "baking in" the value of `this` of the scope of the new function.

Let's take this function for example:

```
function printTheValueOfThis() {
    console.log(this)
}

var printHello = printTheValueOfThis.bind('hello')

printHello() // this will output "hello" to the console
```

In your code snippet, the function in question is `console.log`
and the "error information" is bound to the second argument

A functionally equivalent code is not exactly as you suggested, it is more like:

```
db.on('error', (someUnusedArg, errorInfo) => {
  console.log('connection error:', errorInfo)
});
```

Many people have written about the `bind` function. If you want to read more, this is one place you can read about it: [bind Method (Function)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/bind-method-function-javascript)